# Why internet explorer 6 trying to save all webpages?

Tags: wine, browser, playonlinux

I have successfully installed IE 6 using playonlinux, but I'm unable to browse any site. when I'm entering any address in the address bar, following message is pops up

> You are downloading the file: / from www.google.com
>
> Would you like to open the file or save it to your computer?

Some days ago I had installed IE 6 using same procedure, then it was perfect,but now I don't know why this is happening? Very weird problem indeed. Hope this will be solved easily.

Comment: Why are you using internet explorer 6 in the first place?

Comment: @AnotherGoogler , Actually, I need Internet Explorer 6 very badly for a specific online application. Without IE 6 that application is not fully functional.

Comment: Try checking in internet options. Sometimes it may hide in there (put all security settings on the lowest)

Comment: @AnotherGoogler, thanks for your suggestion, already done that, but no improvement.